# Selective tracking of mouse in QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

I'm relatively new to Qt.

I am writing an application where I am generating a pseudorandom numbers and keys and I would like to seed the generators with random mouse movements captured within a `QMainWindow`. Additionally, I would like to be able to turn this feature off and on when the user presses a `QButton`.

From what I understand I should be able to use `connect()` and `disconnect()` to a signal in `QMainWindow` that is emitted when the user moves the mouse. Is this the best approach?

My problem is I'm not sure what signal I should connect to. I have searched the Qt Documentation but can't find a signal that's generated when the mouse is moved over a `QWidget`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override `void QWidget::mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )` in your `QMainWindow` to capture the mouse move events. see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent

You probably want to do an `event->ignore()` in the override to allow propagation of the event.

You also have to enable mouse tracking with `void setMouseTracking ( bool enable )` to receive mouse move event when no button is pressed. see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop